# How to rate limit JEE CDI Events to stop "429 Too Many Requests"

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am developing a JEE application that extracts data from reference sites using public RESTful API's.

My application is employing Asynchronous CDI events to trigger multiple calls to these RESTful API's.

I wish to be a "Polite" and "Considerate" user of these API resources and have attempted to stagger my API calls by a random number of millisconds
using Retrofit and RxJava as follows:-

```
final Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> apiResponse = service.searchEuropePmc(queryParams);
compositeDisposable.add(apiResponse.delaySubscription(randomDelay(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(response -> reportResponse(response)));
```

This approach has alleviated the issue, however I am still experiencing errors such as this:-

```
08:49:53,779 ERROR [stderr] (RxComputationThreadPool-3) <html><body><h1>429 Too Many Requests</h1>
08:49:53,779 ERROR [stderr] (RxComputationThreadPool-3) You've sent too many requests in a given amount of time. Please slow down and try again soon.
08:49:53,779 ERROR [stderr] (RxComputationThreadPool-3) </body></html>
```

This is due to the fact I have a pool of 10 EJB's concurrently making these API calls.

How can I stagger/schedule these concurrent EJB calls in such a way that I do not receive any more "429 Too Many Requests"?

Is my only option to use a single threaded model?

Comment: Use 1 EJB in the pool? That reduces it by a factor of 10...

Comment: @Kukeltje, that would definitely resolve my issue, however I was looking for a more elegant solution than going Single Threaded. I was hoping I could use some type of CDI Event choreographer and/or scheduler to control the event consumption rate.

Comment: _"I was hoping I could use some type of CDI Event choreographer and/or scheduler to control the event consumption rate."_ would that not be creating a 'queue'? If using 1 EJB would cause problems at the 'producer' (timeouts getting a bean from the pool) and since your are using JEE, you could use JMS with one consunme rsince that is sort of what your are creating, a real queue which JMS effectively is. Most JMS consumers can be configured to have throttling.

Comment: I feel like you are overcomplicating the matter. Using singlethreaded model would work just fine; or offloading it all to one another thread.  BTW you can still use CDI async events but only dedicate single thread to the execution via `NotificationOptions` (of using Weld's specific settings). You could also leverage EJB's `Timer` service and aggregate requests for a period of time and then send one larger request (not sure it's applicable for your case though).